# When should I merge my Cobertura ser files rather than reusing and adding to one?

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura

I am running several processes for code coverage. For example, unit tests and manual tests, etc. I want an overview of coverage for all the ways in which I exercised the code.

Why not just specify the same *.ser* file for Cobertura each time? Cobertura will add new data to the *ser* file.

On the other hand, under what circumstances should I use separate *.ser* files, then run the *cobertura-merge* command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible example is when your codebase is fragmented, compiled and packaged independently, and you run your unit-tests on each portion independently. You can then merge your .ser files to have a complete picture for your application.

If you use 'common' modules for multiple applications/binaries, you can also get a more accurate picture of the actual coverage of each application, specifically, if that is important to you.

Another scenario would be a situation where you run unit tests on your codebase and collect a .ser file, then you also instrument your binaries and run automation testing, as well as functional (manual) testing, each time collecting your .ser files.
If you generate the reports independently, you can't just open a spreadsheet and add up the coverage numbers, because it's likely many coverage paths were identical in all scenarios.

Only by merging these .ser files will you get an accurate picture of what paths were executed, and which ones were not exercised in ANY of your testing scenarios.

---

**Edit**: I realize I had a partial answer - my apologies. You asked

> Why not just specify the same .ser file for Cobertura each time?
>   Cobertura will add new data to the ser file.

However, I feel it is a matter of personal preferences. First of all, to be able to 'reuse' the .ser file thru the successive testing scenarios, you need some sort of a test pipeline with no external dependencies. If you have that condition met, then I don't have any objections to doing it this way if it's more practical to you.

Personally, I prefer to break it down into individual .ser files and aggregate them later. For one thing, if one step fails and I need to re-run it, I don't have to worry about it. Additionally, if you are ever interested into the specifics of each testing step, you can also pull out the report for it, whereas in your pipeline scenario you can't. Still not very compelling.

Comment: That explains when to merge ser files rather than generate completely independent reports. What are the conditions under which I should add more and more info into one ser file through multiple independent tests, as compared to merging ser files?

Comment: I edited my answer to try and reply to this as well.